# wordpress generated inline css missing after migration

Tags: css, migration

- migrated working wordpress setup form the local development setup to the production environment
- changed the siteurl/home in the wp_options database table
- everything seems ok at first glace

Problem: Some inline css blocks are missing or incomplete messing up the layout

Question: What could cause this behaviour and how to fix it?

The image shows code form the production environment with only 4 inline css sections while the development version below includes several `<style="wp-block...inline-css">` sections.

[image: The code above shows the production environment with only 4 inline css sections while the development version includes several wp-block...inline-css sections]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy the website locally and I ran into the same issue. In the end I used a Migration Plugin (BackupBliss – Backup Migration Staging) and created a Backup on the staging page. Then I created a blank Wordpress install on the target server and added the same plugin to restore the backup. Everything now looks and works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and after deleting all transients with WP-CLI the issue was resolved.

```
wp transient delete —-all
```

On a local environnement it should not happen if you use the [WP_DEVELOPMENT_MODE](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/14/configuring-development-mode-in-6-3/) constant appropriately.